# Best solution to host a (command line) Windows application?

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, hosting, cloud-hosting, appharbor

I have a Windows application that does some calculations and is called from command line. On my Windows machine, I have a PHP script running under Apache that executes the application and shows the output.

Is there any hosting solution that I can use to do the same? I can't figure out if EC2 or Azure are the right solutions. Basically, I need a web server + ability to execute my application.

Suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can host your application on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/), the .NET Platform-as-a-Service. You can either port your web frontend to .NET or try to get your PHP stuff working with [Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/). AppHarbor is working on [Background Tasks](http://feedback.appharbor.com/forums/95687-general/suggestions/1370747-background-jobs?ref=title), which might be a good match for your workload.

Answer (score 2):

I would just run the PHP script you already have under IIS in a Windows Azure web role.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Windows Application and you have the source code I would go with an Azure Worker Role. The advantage of using a PaaS (as Azure) instead of an IaaS (as Amazon) is that you wont have to bother of keeping the server up to date.

The real investment in time will be when you rewrite your application to make it work as a Worker Role. The time needed to do this work depends on how your application works right now. If is uses a lot of disc access it might be difficult and perhaps an Amazon server would be better. But if it only crunches numbers in memory an Azure Worker Role is a very good candidate.

The real advantage of using an Amazon server is that you probably wont need to do any work at all. Except maintaining the server.

Comment: Could also run the whole thing (the PHP site *and* the command line tool) in an Azure Web Role. Seems it ought to be straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the question both Azure and EC2 will do the job very well. This is the kind of task both systems are designed for.

So the question becomes really: which is *best*? That depends on two things: what the application needs to do and your own experience and preference.

As it's a Windows application there should probably be a leaning towards Azure. While EC2 supports Windows, the tooling and support resources for Azure are probably deeper at this point.

If cost is a factor then a (somewhat outdated) resource is here: http://blog.mccrory.me/2010/10/30/public-cloud-hourly-cost-comparison/ -- the conclusion is that, by and large, Azure and Amazon are roughly similar for compute charges.

Answer (score 0):

Steve Marx has a [blog post](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-other-web-servers-on-windows-azure) that describes how to run another web server (i.e not IIS) on Azure
This potentially has everything you need - you can deploy Apache and your executable and run it in exactly the same way.

Alternatively - you can deploy your executable along side a bit of code in a worker role that would run that application periodically, all depending on your exact requirements